The specified file cannot be found. Xamarin Forms
I need to read a text file that is located in the assets folder:

But an error occurs: the specified file could not be found:
(2): C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\App1\App1\App1.Android\obj\Debug\130\assets.

You need to copy the file to the bin folder when building: Right click the file, properties, select Copy to Output Directory and set it Copy Always.
